# Firebase: Is it possible to update individual children across multiple parents?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to update individual children across multiple parents without overriding other children?

Here's what my Firebase data looks like:

```
notifications:
    uniquenotif1:
        a: true
        b: true
    uniquenotif2:
        a: true
        b: true
```

My attempt with Swift to update just the children with the name `a`:

```
notificationsRef.updateChildValues([uniquenotif1: [a:false], uniquenotif2: [a:false])
```

This results in the data are as follows:

```
notifications:
    uniquenotif1:
        a: false
    uniquenotif2:
        a: false
```

This is what I'd like them to look like:

```
notifications:
    uniquenotif1:
        a: false
        b: true
    uniquenotif2:
        a: false
        b: true
```

The requirement is that this needs to happen as a single operation (I'm using Cloud Functions to send out push notifications dependent on these values).

I don't want to pass in all the values for the children (`a` AND `b`), if possible.

Comment: let get full children then update expected child.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look:

```
let key = ref.child("notifications").childByAutoId().key
let noti = ["a": false,
            "b": true]
let childUpdates = ["/notifications/\(key)": noti]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

You need a `for` loop to generate a series of request. It's my opinion. Please tell me if you have a better solution. ^^

Comment: I have a limitation where I can not pass in any other values other than the value that is being updated.

Comment: Limitation? Can you tell me more?

Comment: I have some cloud functions that listen to changes of these values